# How to finish this equality of an injection?

Tags: functions

I want to prove that:
F(a,b) =  $2^{a-1}(2b-1)$

Is an injection.

Here is my proof so far:

-Assume F(a,b) = F(c,d)
-$2^{a-1}(2b-1)$ = $2^{c-1}(2d-1)$
-......

I know this involves logs, but i am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What is F? Since when is  $2^{a-1}(2b-1)$ a function?

Comment: You're correct. I updated the question

Comment: no it doesn't involve log. Try to think of what happens if a is not equal to c. Can you divide 2 on both sides for a number of times until you can reach some ridiculous conclusion?

Comment: furthermore are you talking about the N^2 to N?

Comment: Yes i am. I cannot figure it out. I am trying every thing but it keeps making the exponents more complicated

Comment: I meant try to proof by contradiction. WOLG, assume a is smaller and divide both sides of your last equation by 2^(a-1) then compare the parity of lhs and rhs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

First show $a=c$ using unique factorisation as a product of primes. Deduce $b=d$.

*Some details*

If $2^{a-1}(2b-1)=2^{c-1}(2d-1)$, by unique factorisation, the $2$-valuations of both sides are equal. Note the $2$-valuation of the l.h.s. is $a-1$  since $2b-1$ is add. Similarly , the $2$-valuation of the r.h.s. is $c-1$. Thus  $a-1=c-1$, hence $a=c$.

Simplifying both sides we get the equality $2b-1=2d-1$, whence $b=d$.

Comment: Can you please show this? I do not understand

Comment: Is the statement "by unique factorisation, the 2-valueations of both sides are equal," just a fact if they are multiplied by an odd number?

Comment: Multiplying by an *odd* number doesn't change the power of $2$.